# How important is the convergence angle of a liquid bipropellant rocket engine

Tags: rockets, engine-design, amateur-rocketry

So I can't exactly find out what angle should the converging part of the rocket chamber be or why different angles are chosen for engines (varies by about 15°).

Are there any guidlines on the angle or equations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Sutton (7th edition online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140722111108/http://web.mit.edu/e_peters/Public/Rockets/Rocket_Propulsion_Elements.pdf)) Chapter 3.4

> The converging nozzle section between the chamber and the nozzle throat has
> never been critical in achieving high performance. The subsonic flow in this
> section can easily be turned at very low pressure drop and any radius, cone
> angle, wall contour curve, or nozzle inlet shape is satisfactory.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't matter. Have read this part, just had to varify. Thank you

Comment: Later in the *Real Nozzles* chapter 3.5 there is some discussion about not making it too short, but it seems that even that is not too important.